# Prototyping a multiplayer game offline, it's crashing when I hit meshes. Can anyone tell why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

So I'm trying to get this game working right offline before I implement the server, and I've had mostly positive results. However, an interesting situation is occuring when the player runs into a collider. It will stutter for a half-second, and unless I pull back in time, it will then freeze. I'm using forces to move, which probably accounts for the reason why. However, I'd like a definite reason.

Yahoo Games Network is my basic service for multiplayer as it lets me write a C# .dll for the server and manage things.

```
void FixedUpdate () {

    RunTime = GetTime();

    mInput.y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    mInput.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    if (Ready)
    {
        SelfTick(RunTime);
        UpdatePlayerInput();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, PlayerController> Target in Targets)
        {

        }
    }   
}

void SelfTick(int T)
{
    Player.FixedStep(T);
}

void UpdatePlayerInput()
{
    if (mInput.x != 0 || mInput.y != 0)
    {
        Player.UpdateInput(mInput);

        // Send Connection Data Here //
    }
}
```

This code runs the main loop, which connects to this on the first player. Everyone else is run in a foreach loop check that sends respective commands:

```
public void FixedStep(int _T)
{
    if (LastTimeStep == 0)
    {
        LastTimeStep = _T;
    }

    int Offset = System.Math.Min(_T - LastTimeStep, 1000);

    for (int i = 0; i < Offset; i++)
    {

        Vector3 actionPoint = transform.position + transform.TransformDirection(buoyancyCentreOffset);
        float forceFactor = 1f - ((actionPoint.y - waterLevel) / floatHeight);

        if (forceFactor > 0f)
        {
            Vector3 uplift = -Physics.gravity * (forceFactor - GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.y * bounceDamp);
            rigidBody.AddForceAtPosition(uplift, actionPoint);
        }

        rigidBody.AddRelativeForce(0f, 0f, mInput.y * Speed);
        rigidBody.AddRelativeTorque(0f, mInput.x * TurnSpeed, 0f);
    }

    LastTimeStep = _T;

    Debug.Log(rigidBody.velocity);
}
```

I was able to see one debug error in one crash instance, which noted that the force applied was too high - Infinite. Most of the time when it crashes, it will crash with no errors. This is the time code that I have:

```
public int GetTime()
{
    System.DateTime EpochStart = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
    int Current_Time = (int)(System.DateTime.UtcNow - EpochStart).TotalMilliseconds;
    return Current_Time;
}
```

Can anyone offer any advice? I'm using Unity3D as my primary game development IDE, with Visual Studio instead of MonoDevelop.

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce the crash in the editor, and not a compiled game? This will make debugging the game and retrieving the error messages much easier.

Comment: These crashes have all occurred in the editor, I haven't compiled the game yet. The best I could get as far as error messages was infinity force before it crashes on me. That only shows up part of the time as well.

Comment: You have a lead to work off of: try doing a Debug.Log where you're applying forces and see what values you're getting.

Comment: I did try that, but in the for loop forces are applied, using Debug crashes immedietly

Answer (score 0):

Set a Min and MAX limit on your uplift variable...to keep it in range and see if it stops crashing. Set a CLAMP function on it before AddForceAtPosition.

Ryan